# Clicking checklist (IE - HTML). Why not work?

Tags: html, vba

Good morning! I am developing a macro to click a few buttons on a page, but some are not working. Does anyone know why?

I posted my worksheet on: http://www.sendspace.com/file/3if8c6

Thanks in advance for any help.

Silmar

Comment: This is not clear at all. Can you explain better what you want to do and how does the macro fails?

Comment: People are more likely to offer help if you post the problem code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In the spreadsheet I posted a picture with the 02 buttons that can not click. Anyway, I'll post the code here.

Thanks!

```
Sub test()
Dim ie
Dim obj
Dim obj2
Dim linkCollection2
Dim elemCollection
Dim t As Integer
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer

Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
ie.Navigate2 "http://www.infomoney.com.br/mercados/agendas"
 ie.Visible = True

Do While ie.Busy
Loop
Do Until ie.Document.ReadyState = "complete"
Loop

Dim LinkFound As Boolean
Dim linkCollection

Set linkCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("A")
For Each link In linkCollection
If link.InnerText = "Resultados" Then
LinkFound = True
link.Click
Exit For
End If

Next

If Not LinkFound Then
MsgBox "Link Not Found!"
Exit Sub
End If

Do While ie.Busy
Loop
Do Until ie.Document.ReadyState = "complete"
Loop

    For Each obj In ie.Document.All.Item("ctl00$cphContent$ctl02$ddlReferencePage").Options
        If obj.InnerText = "3T12" Then
            obj.Selected = True
          '  ie.Document.forms(0).submit
            Exit For
        End If
    Next obj

    Set linkCollection2 = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("A")
For Each link In linkCollection2
If link.InnerText = "Resultados" Then
LinkFound = True
link.Click
Exit For
End If

Next
        Set elemCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
        For t = 0 To elemCollection.Length - 1
        For r = 0 To elemCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1
            For c = 0 To elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).InnerText
            Next c
        Next r
    Next t

    ' The error happens here
' TO FROM HERE DOES NOT WORK. WHY?

    For Each obj2 In ie.Document.All.Item("tblCInvestorData_length").Options
        If obj.InnerText = "100" Then
            obj2.Selected = True
          '  ie.Document.forms(0).submit
            Exit For
        End If
    Next obj2

End Sub
```

Comment: Most obvious issue seems to be that in your last loop you check the innerText of `obj` and not `obj2`

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, but is giving error in execution. See what I did:
[CODE]For Each obj2 In ie.document.all.Item("tblCInvestorData_length").Options ' IS GIVING ERROR IN THIS LINE
        If obj2.innerText = "*100*" Then
            obj2.Selected = True
                      Exit For
        End If
    Next obj2[/CODE]